# This is why this site suffers from a lack of talent

Tags: bug

Its an uphill challenge to get good information out of this site to the point where I usually look elsewhere. If the users here want to attract better talent and better answers then the attitude has to change. I posted a very timely and relevant question for many server admins, and I get a manual in response. Whats the point?

[Putty Settings Disappeared on Windows 10 after May 2020 Update](https://serverfault.com/questions/1019023/putty-settings-disappeared-on-windows-10-after-may-2020-update)

Comment: Please downvote this post. I want to have the most downvoted post of all time. It will reveal to the greater world how backwards and gatekeeping this site is to google. When people search for questions this site will become irrelevant because the users don't answer questions.

Comment: Petulance won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

We are a site aiming for professional system administrator.

I can **easily** understand the downvote for that sentence alone;

> don't downvote me if that concerns you and makes you upset, just be a
>   jerk in the comments section.

Your question could have been good, but don't tell me you didn't expected to be downvoted with such sentence ?

Second point, you got a answer in comment. He linked to a good source. The user even edited the link to be sure it go directly to that section : **A.5.2 Where does PuTTY store its data?**. Why the bashing  ? He didnt posted a RTFM comment, he linked directly to the data you seek. We are not paid to help, we don't own you anything, but don't bash someone that try to help you. It's the best way to make sure no one else try to answer you. (and the best way to finish with a cooldown suspension period)

Third point, such question are more on-topic on superuser.com, which too make it more downvoted here.

Please cooldown and I will migrate your question, as for me your other question as for me it's just off-topic here.

Comment: Exactly. You guys decide everything is off-topic and you're going to send me into the cesspool of stupidity. I would contribute here, but I'd be wasting my breath. If you guys want professional serveradmins, then figure out a way to accept them into your community and take care of them when they have questions.

Comment: And seriously, I know it gets under some people's skin when I ask them to not downvote me. It must be really hard not to click that down arrow of superiority when someone asks for mercy and forgiveness before they post. I needed an answer to a question. I didnt get it here. End of story

Comment: @JMC For reference, the link gave go directly to that;  *On Windows, PuTTY stores most of its data (saved sessions, SSH host keys) in the Registry. The precise location is

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY*

Comment: My name isn't SimonTatham and i'm not logged in as him. I figured out how to solve the issue by looking at previous restore points, but thats not the issue I'm bringing up. But thanks man for trying to help solve the issue

Comment: @JMC Thats the app(putty) author's name BTW

Comment: I know you're a good dude. I'm just frustrated with how people act on here and I know the site could be much greater if we all band together and start helping each other solve issues. Thats why stackexchange was created

Comment: I can also see how I look like the asshole. To put it simply, many times I've asked simple questions here that server admins should be able to answer. When I post those questions I typically get downvoted, villified, and told my question belongs in another forum. However, I'm a professional server admin. The things I ask are timely and relevant. So who is in the wrong? The community or the people paid to do the job? You're right, no-one owes me anything, but the greater internet will eventually answer the question. The home for those questions should be the community i've been part of serverf

Answer (score 5):

The site used to have considerable talent but it mostly moved on when it got bored answering basic questions that already have answers here or are easily found elsewhere, reading manuals as a service (like you want) and generally having to waste too much time wading through those questions to find something interesting.

The site has been in considerable decline for some time I present as evidence https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/303570/answer-rate-over-time#graph

You got an answer as a comment and a link, that's better than most questions. That you didn't understand it and chose to whinge rather than educate yourself ...